# Deserialize GenericXMLSecurityToken from JsonResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

When trying to deserialize a GenericXMLSecurityToken from an HTTPResponseMessage I get the following exception:

> "Could not create an instance of type
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityKeyIdentifierClause. Type is an
>   interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path
>   'internalTokenReference.assertionId', line 1, position 162."

On the server the serialized object is created using

```
new JsonResult(genericToken)
```

where `genericToken` is a `GenericXmlSecurityToken`. On the client side I am using

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:44359/api/TokenService/RequestToken", requestcontent);
String responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
GenericXMLSecurityToken result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenericXMLSecurityToken>(responseString);
```

however the last line throws an exception with the text above. I understand the error in so much as I know I can't instantiate that type because it's abstract, is there another way I can serialize this type to get around this or is it just not serializable to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I never solved this issue, I simply bypassed it by returning the XML representation as a string instead (`GenericXmlSecurityToken.TokenXml.OuterXml`).